# eclipse xml editor indent using spaces

Tags: xml, eclipse, indentation

My eclipse version is  Mars Release (4.5.0).Preferences->XML－>XML Files->Editor,I can not set the value of Indentation size. The "+" and "-"　can not be clicked . I can not input value yet!

Comment: This applies to STS-3.7.2 as well

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Had the same problem, I found the following workaround:

1. open with a text editor this file in your workspace folder:
   **.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.prefs**
2. change or add the following line ("4" is just an example): **indentationSize=4**
3. (Re)start Eclipse

Comment: According to this method ,I have solved the problem .Thanks!+1

Comment: If the file isn't there just change the max line length and apply in Eclipse and the file will be created. Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be due to a bug that is not yet fixed/released. See more at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=428246

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Eclipse. It is related to GTK3: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=428246

It was originally reported in early 2014 for the Kepler release.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kollgandren's answer, if you want to use spaces as your indent, include two options in your `${WORKSPACE}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.prefs` file.

```
indentationChar=space
indentationSize=4
```